# Connection issues to different routers with the same settings

Tags: wireless-networking, wireless-router, raspberry-pi

I recently ran into a very weird issue regarding connecting a Raspberry Pi to a router. The issue is solved, but not the root cause. I wonder if anyone can enlighten know more about this.

I hope I've described the setup enough.

### Setup

I have a remote location with a 4G router (Netgear basic pocket-wifi style from telecom company) from where I collect some data.

I had two Raspberry Pi Zero W with Raspbian Lite (calling these 'devices' from now on) running that connected to the router without problem.

I went to install two more identical devices. But before I did this I tried simulating the router by setting SSID and password of my phone hotspot to the same as the router. Just to know that it worked (had issues with this before). The devices connected to the phone's hotspot without problem.

When I am on site to install the devices the old devices are connected to the router, no problem. But when I install the new devices they won't connect to the router at all but works towards the hotspot just fine. If I turn off the router the "old" devices connect to the hotspot immediately, so the settings are correct.

To test, I setup a new router, a "proper" router (TP-Link Archer), and all four devices connect without problem straight away.

### Question

1. Why did the new devices not connect to the pocket-wifi style router when the security settings are the same SSID, PSK, WPA2-PSK but it works with the the new router?

Answer (score 0):

Router 1

Set up this router as normal. In the wi-fi safety settings of the router, disable Automatic Channel choice and manually set the channel to channel 3.

Router 2

In most cases, this router should be wired to the authentic router. Consider a wi-fi media bridge or by means of jogging a single community cable in this case to a different location.

Disable the DHCP server on this router to stop IP conflicts or community configuration problems allowing solely Router 1 to manipulate the network.
Manually set the IP Address of this router to 1 quantity greater than the present most important router, for instance, if your router IP is 192.168.1.1, set this router to 192.168.1.2.

Please make positive this tackle is out of the 1st router's allotment of addresses for DHCP distribution. If not, please make a DHCP reservation for this router's tackle in router 1's DHCP table.
Set the Internet Gateway of router two to router 1's IP address.
Connect the two routers with the use of a wired connection from any of ports 1-4 in router 1 to any of ports 1-4 in router two You can use a Wireless Media Bridge or Powerline Ethernet Kit to create a wired connection. DO NOT use router 2's WAN port.

In the wi-fi protection settings of this router, disable Automatic Channel choice and manually set the channel to channel eight - or any different channel now not being used via the predominant router or any different router on this community (it is feasible to set extra than two routers for definitely massive areas).
Set up wi-fi safety to be equal in router two as it is in router 1.

Comment: I'm sorry, this didn't answer my question. I appreciate tips on how to actually solve it but the question is why did this happend? Also, I don't want two routers, I replaced the first one with the second.